# Unity3D Raycasting with Oculus Rift Integration / Measuring the distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, measure, oculus

I want to measure the distance between two points in Unity3D Game Engine using the Oculus Rift. The points are targeted by the user by looking at point A, pressing alpha1 on the keyboard and B, pressing alpha2 on the keyboard. I got this far:

```
     #pragma strict

 private var measuring = false;
 private var startPoint : Vector3;
 private var dist;

 function Update() {
     var hit : RaycastHit; 
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)) {
         dist = 0.0f;
         if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), hit)) {
         // if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit, 10)) {
            measuring = true;
            startPoint = hit.point; 
         }

     }
     if (measuring && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2)) {
         if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), hit)) {
         // if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit, 10)) {
          dist = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, hit.point);
         }
     }
 }

 function OnGUI() {
     if (measuring) {
         GUI.Label(Rect(50,50,180,50), "Distance: " + dist.ToString());
     }
 }
```

My problem is, that this code only works with the standard main camera object, but I want to use the Oculus integrated OVRCameraRig. I get the following exception message:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MeasureInGame.Update () (at Assets/MeasureInGame.js:11)

I found a solution on this site: https://kaharri.com/unity-gaming-shootingaiming-part3-oculus/ I created a ShotSpawner object as a child of OVRCameraRig (this should act like a gun in front of the camera) and changed the Raycast to

```
     Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit, 10)
```

to get the users view. But it also doesn't seem to work.

How can I get the aiming done with the Oculus a Main Camera. And is it correct that I strictly need to have a collider on my objects to be measured or is there a solution without collider?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - are you really using the mouse with Oculus? Of course you can, but the standard way is to look at the selected object (cursor is in the center of viewport). Cast the ray from the "middle" eye in the oculus integration - it's the object that is the parent to the left and right eyes. Use this ray instead of the one from `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay`:

```
// add a reference to the middleEyeGameobject 
// in your class and link it in the inspector
var ray=new Ray(middleEyeGameobject.transform.position, middleEyeGameobject.transform.forward);
```

Also, you don't have to specify the distance with hit raycast (remove the fourth parameter to `Physics.Raycast`).

---

And for the additional question yes, everything has to have a collider with `Physics.Raycast`. And yes, there are other ways to do this, but the [built in ones](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.Raycast.html) ([2](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.IntersectRay.html)) still require colliders (or similar), although they can be virtual, not attached to objects.

It's best to use colliders, perhaps on [their own layer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html).

Comment: If it works thanks to my answer then accept/+1 it, please.

Answer (score 0):

The NullReferenceException you are getting is because you are using **Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)** , **camera.main** uses the **MainCamera tag** which is not set for your OVRCameraRig. You can set tag of this camera as mainCamera if OVRCameraRig is supposed to be your mainCamera or otherwise you can take reference of this camera (OVRCameraRig) and use cameraRef.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition). :)